# How does one change the position of a Slider in SwiftUI?

Tags: slider, swiftui

I am trying to update/set my slider value within a button press action.

```
        Button(action: {
            if self.questionNum == 1{
                print("End")
            }else{
                self.questionNum -= 1

                //This line here is where the value is being set.

                self.slider.value = self.model.answers[self.questionNum - 1] as! Double

                print(self.model.answers)
                print(self.slider.value)
                self.questionOpacity = 0
                self.model.currentQuestion = self.model.questions[self.questionNum - 1]
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
                    withAnimation(){
                        self.questionOpacity = 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }) {
            Text("Previous Question")
                .font(.system(size: 25))
                .fontWeight(.medium)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
```

The slider value actually changes but the dial does not move or update to represent the new value. My Slider value is coming from an Observable object like this one:

```
class SliderVal: ObservableObject {

var didChange = PassthroughSubject<SliderVal,Never>()
var value = 50.0 {
   willSet {
    print(self.value)
 }
}
```

The default value of the slider is set to 50 which is the middle, is there any way I can both set and update the slider value to values stored in my array? Outputting the slider value actually gives me the correct result so why is it that the slider dial is not moving/updating?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

example:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var number : Float

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Slider(value: $number, in: 1...100)
                .padding()
            Text("You've selected \(Int(number))")
        }.onAppear() {
            self.number = 30
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The pattern you use for `ObservableObject` is outdated (it was valid for Beta, now it is not). Instead use default `@Published` property wrapper, it will update your view automatically, and provides corresponding bindings if needed.

So here how should your model look...

```
class SliderVal: ObservableObject {
    @Published var value = 50.0
}
```

and in view (as I understood), it should be declared

```
@ObservedObject var slider = SliderVal()
```

Comment: Okay I see, what about willSet and didSet implementations? I am using these in my Observable Object to receive constant updates of the Slider value. Also now I have implemented the above code the slider does not update when pressing my button that changes its value. - thanks

Comment: I don't have your complete code to test, but `willSet`/`didSet` is not needed, usually, instead the direct binding to `ObservedObject` is used, eg. `$slider.value`